# error in BatchNorm2d in pytorch CNN model

Tags: python, image, pytorch, conv-neural-network, batchnorm

my database has grayscale images of size 128 * 128* 1   each  with batch size =10
i am using cnn model but I got this error in BatchNorm2d
expected 4D input (got 2D input)

I posted the way which i used to transform my image (gray scale - tensor - normalize ) and divide it to batches

```
data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
        transforms.Resize(128),
        transforms.CenterCrop(128),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.5], [0.5])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
        transforms.Resize(128),
        transforms.CenterCrop(128),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.5], [0.5])
    ]),
}


data_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/pytorch'
dsets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x), data_transforms[x])
         for x in ['train', 'val']}
dset_loaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dsets[x], batch_size=10,
                                               shuffle=True, num_workers=25)
                for x in ['train', 'val']}
dset_sizes = {x: len(dsets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
dset_classes = dsets['train'].classes
```

I used this model

```
class HeartNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=7):
        
        super(HeartNet, self).__init__()

        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ELU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ELU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ELU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ELU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ELU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ELU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
            )

        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(16*16*256, 2048),
            nn.ELU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(2048),
            nn.Linear(2048, num_classes)
            )

        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.classifier[1].weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.classifier[4].weight)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), 16 * 16 * 256)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: The problem is how you input your data. The input for the model is 4D which is correct, as the data should be in the form `(batch_size,x,y,channels)`. My best guess is that since your image is grayscale it's dropped the last dimension, and for some reason you are entering the data with `batch_size = 1' which in turn makes it a 2D input. Can't say for sure without more code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the batch norm layer inside your `self.classifier` sub network: While your `self.features` sub network is fully convolutional and required `BatchNorm2d`, the `self.classifier` sub network is a fully-connected multi-layer perceptron (MLP) network and is 1D in nature. Note the how the `forward` function removes the spatial  dimensions from the feature map `x` before feeding it to the classifier.

Try replacing the `BatchNorm2d` in `self.classifier` with `BatchNorm1d`.